# Remove all edges between a subset of nodes

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph `g` and a list of nodes, `subset_nodes`, in the graph. I want to remove all the edges between nodes `v_i`, `v_j` where both `v_i` and `v_j` in `subset_nodes`.

I am currently using the following approach:

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph.Full(10)
subset_nodes = [g.vs[i] for i in range(4)]

to_delete = set()
for node in subset_nodes:
    for v in node.neighbors():
        if v in subset_nodes:
            tp = (node.index, v.index) 
            to_delete.add( tuple(sorted(tp)) )

print(len(g.es))
g.delete_edges( to_delete )
print(len(g.es))
```

This prints:

```
45
39
```

which makes sense because

```
10 choose 2 = 45   # total # of edges (since it is a full graph)
4 choose 2 = 6     # # of removed edges
45 - 6 = 39        # # of edges remaining
```

My question is, is there a better, more elegant or more pythonic way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution would be:

```
from igraph import Graph
g = Graph.Full(10)
g.es.select(_within=range(4)).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Igraph has "induced_subgraph" method which can come handy for a more concise solution:

```
import igraph as ig
g=ig.Graph.Full(10)
subset_nodes=[g.vs[i] for i in range(4)]
smallgraph=g.induced_subgraph(subset_nodes)
es=ig.EdgeSeq(smallgraph)
mytup=[e.tuple for e in es]
g.delete_edges(mytup)
```